# IOS 13 Dark Mode Accent Colour

Tags: ios-darkmode

In macOS 10.14 the user can select between light and dark mode and can also select from a choice of 8 accent/highlight colours.

In IOS 13 the user can select between light and dark mode but the accent/highlight colour is either mode appears to me to be fixed to blue (or at least I haven't so far worked out how to change it).

Does anyone know if the accent/highlight colour on IOS is likely to change in the future to a user choice as in macOS, because I would like to be able to use this colour in my app.

Is the (currently fixed blue) accent/highlight colour for IOS 13 accessible and is so how do I get access to it as a colour, from Objective C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue you are seeing is iOS' default `tintColor`. You can set that on a view basis or, if you want to override it app-wide, set it on your `UIWindow`. If a view doesn't have a `tintColor` explicitly set, it uses the `tintColor` of its superview—all the way up to the window.

Comment: Thanks for identifying it. My question was really "Can that changed system wide by the user?" Because it if could I would want to react to such a change in my app.

Comment: Not right now, no. You, the developer, need to pick the accent color of your app.